# Google Chrome: Text will not minimize correctly

Tags: html, css

Google Chrome is really throwing a roadblock at me and I need some help.

I am setting up a menu and the text is wrapping when zooming out (<50%). I do not want to use white-space: nowrap and I cannot make my menu wider. Safari, Firefox, even IE - no problems however when zooming out with chrome it forces a word wrap. Any ideas. Please let me know if more html/css is needed, i tried to simplify things:

CSS:

```
#page{
    display: block;
    overflow:visible;
    font:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background:#956e41;
}

#header{
    width:auto;
    max-width:1105px;
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow:visible;
}

#mainPicture{
    height:475px;
    width: 1105px;
    background-image:url(images/main.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

#headerFrame{
    height:80px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1080px;
    background-color: #a15535;
    position: relative;
}

#logo{
    height: 150px;
    width: 340px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:url(images/logo.png);
    float: left;
}

#menuFrame{
    width:auto;
    max-width: 740px; 
    margin: auto;
    width: 1080px;
    display:inline-block;

}

#menu{
    width:auto;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin: 0 0 0 0 ;   
    text-align:right;
    display:inline-block;
}

#menu ul{
    margin-left: 80px;  
}

#menu ul li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 0;         
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="mainPicture"></div>
            <div id="headerFrame" class="borderSq">
            <div id="logo">
                <!--<img src="images/logo.png" />-->
            </div>
            <div id="menuFrame">    
                <div id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="border li">menu1<br /><span>text</span></li>
                        <li class="border li">THE menu1<br /><span>text</span></li>
                        <li class="border li">menu1<br /><span>text</span></li>
                        <li class="li">menu1<br /><span>text</span></li>
                    </ul>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some of the CSS may look redundant, i lost my cool and started just throwing stuff at it... never good.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X48ng/

^Open with chrome and zoom out.... you'll see (scroll right too for text)

John

Comment: There is a limit to how small fonts can be shrunk in a browser. Why should this be a problem? Do you expect users to be zooming that far out on your page? If they do something that unexpected, they shouldn't be surprised when the layout malfunctions. It's the virtual equivalent of opening your hard drive case and voiding the warranty.

Comment: I could not reproduce this. Could I see a screenshot and maybe a demo?

Comment: @Parallel2ne here is the screenshot... http://oi40.tinypic.com/bgvdr5.jpg, i hope it is sufficient. Thank you.

Comment: to recreate this in the fiddle you need to zoom out to about 33%, but i agree with the comment by Blazemonger, but i can't think of any logical reason why this would be happening... although you have set defined widths and height, so as the page starts to shrink due to zooming, this might be forcing a new line? its the only thing i can think of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think i see exactly what is causing it but its a bit of a fiddle with what you want from this,

After messing with the fiddle a bit I managed to stop the menu items being pushed to a new line when zooming out to 33% by removing the `margin-left` on the `#menu ul{}` item,

As shown here:
[js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X48ng/1/) (still happens when zoomed out to 25% but now can zoom out to 33% instead of just 50%)

The only thing I can think of that is causing this is; as the page is resized the margin is being enlarged or something along those lines,

if anyone can help improve this answer, please do.

steve.

Comment: @IGoogledGoogle... I was playing with it more last night and came upon a similar fix... Thank you for confirming this. It is true no one will most likely do this- I have a problem with being too picky about things. In the end this will be adequate.

Comment: no problem, glad I could help, one question, does this happen with other browsers at all?

Comment: It would with safari a little... IE handled it extremely well. Firefox wasn't bad either. The main difference between firefox/safari and chrome is they don't allow the user to zoom as much as chrome allows. IE on the other hand has much larger zoom capabilities than chrome.... and it can maintain the div proportions perfectly in my opinion.